# linking llvm produced object code with ld

Tags: gcc, llvm, ld

I have written a small compiler that uses llvm (through c++) to produce object files (in a linux system).

When I link the compiled output with gcc, the program runs fine:

```
myCompiler source.mylang -o objCode
gcc objCode -o program
./program #runs fine
```

But if I try to link it with ld, I get a segmentation fault when I run the program:

```
myCompiler source.mylang -o objCode
ld objCode -e main -o program   #ld does not print any error or warning.
./program #Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Here is the llvm code that the compiler outputs (using myLlvmModule->print function):

```
; ModuleID = 'entryPointModule'
source_filename = "entryPointModule"

define i32 @main() {
entry:
  %x = alloca i32
  store i32 55, i32* %x
  ret i32 0
  ret i32 0
}
```

Why ld fails, when gcc succeeds?
I thought that after writting a compiler, the only needed step would be to call a linker. Is an other compiler (such as gcc) necessary?

If yes, why?
If no, how can I have ld working?

EDIT:
readelf -d of the working binary:

```
Dynamic section at offset 0xe00 contains 24 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000000c (INIT)               0x4b8
 0x000000000000000d (FINI)               0x684
 0x0000000000000019 (INIT_ARRAY)         0x200df0
 0x000000000000001b (INIT_ARRAYSZ)       8 (bytes)
 0x000000000000001a (FINI_ARRAY)         0x200df8
 0x000000000000001c (FINI_ARRAYSZ)       8 (bytes)
 0x000000006ffffef5 (GNU_HASH)           0x298
 0x0000000000000005 (STRTAB)             0x348
 0x0000000000000006 (SYMTAB)             0x2b8
 0x000000000000000a (STRSZ)              125 (bytes)
 0x000000000000000b (SYMENT)             24 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000015 (DEBUG)              0x0
 0x0000000000000003 (PLTGOT)             0x200fc0
 0x0000000000000007 (RELA)               0x3f8
 0x0000000000000008 (RELASZ)             192 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000009 (RELAENT)            24 (bytes)
 0x000000000000001e (FLAGS)              BIND_NOW
 0x000000006ffffffb (FLAGS_1)            Flags: NOW PIE
 0x000000006ffffffe (VERNEED)            0x3d8
 0x000000006fffffff (VERNEEDNUM)         1
 0x000000006ffffff0 (VERSYM)             0x3c6
 0x000000006ffffff9 (RELACOUNT)          3
 0x0000000000000000 (NULL)               0x0
```

the same command for the corrupt binary:

```
There is no dynamic section in this file.
```

Comment: You need to link with the C run-time library.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runtime_library

Comment: can you post the output of `readelf -d` of the two produced final binaries? also, what happens when you run this with `gdb`? what's the backtrace?

Comment: And gdb says "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
"

Comment: As for the readelf, I update the post and I included the outputs.

Comment: ewindes, Could you please explain me why I need the c-runtime library? The program does no more than declaring a variable and return. I would like to understand what the c runtime lib would add to the program. Also, when I add -lc in the ld command, the final binary would not execute at all. I get "bash: ../data/pr: No such file or directory", even though it does exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your entry point attempts to return to a return address on the stack which does not exist, which is why the program jumps to address zero.

The entry point of a program is not expected to return.  It must terminate the process by calling `_exit` (or a related system call).

Comment: I see. So I guess I should wrap the main method to some other, and then do the system call. I will try it out as soon as posible! Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: Florian Weimer, do you know if llvm library can emmit a syscall instruction in order to terminate the program? I did the wrapping function (I called it _start) and just called main. Now I must add the syscall, but I do not find any such instruction http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1IRBuilder.html...

Comment: I don't think LLVM supports the syscall calling convention natively. You need to use inline assembler or call a separate function written in assembler.

Comment: Florian Weimer, I finally made it work. The problem was, exactly as you said, the exiting of the program.
I did the following: I wrapped my main function (which returns an int) to an other, which I called _customStart. This method  never really returns. It calls main, and then exit() from C lib, with the return value of main, as an agrument (which is the exit code of the program).
I then called ld with -e _customStart, plus some of link options that gcc also does (I compiled a tiny program with gcc -v to see the link options).
The program now runs fine, and the exit code is also respected.

Comment: I preferred using exit() instead of writing an inline asm, because the second would be OS and architecture specific, so I would have to deal with all this complexity myself.